# Conda PackageNotFoundError - unable to install packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, data-science

I'm trying to install a set of libraries used in a data science course, following the instructions from [this url](https://github.com/bonzanini/VideoCourse-DataAnalysisPython), under "Setting up the environment". I have installed Acaconda3 using Python 3.6 on a Windows 10 machine. I have a previously installed version of Python 2.7 which I suspect is the problem, but I´m not sure how to solve this (both versions are now listed in the environment settings).

The problem starts when trying to install the libraries, which gives me the following error when I open a command prompt and enter a "conda install ... " command. The .txt file I´m trying to read is in the project folder. How can I install the packages properly? (anaconda administrator allows a workaround by letting you select the packages and install them from there, but I´d like to know why the command prompt doesn´t work in this case).

```
        (packt-py36) C:\Users\Eric\AnacondaProjects>conda install --file 
        conda-reqs.txt --yes
        Fetching package metadata .............

        PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't working because the list of packages was created for OS X. I was able to successfully import these packages on OS X but there are several packages and versions that are not compatible. I have gone through the file and eliminated any non-compatible packages for you. Quite a few packages are missing but you will be able to install from this.

This file may be used to create an environment using:

`$ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>`

platform: win-64

```
bleach=1.5.0
cycler=0.10.0=py36_0
decorator=4.0.11=py36_0
entrypoints=0.2.2=py36_1
freetype=2.5.5
html5lib=0.999=py36_0
icu=57.1
ipykernel=4.6.1=py36_0
ipython=6.0.0=py36_0
ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py36_0
ipywidgets=6.0.0=py36_0
jinja2=2.9.6=py36_0
jsonschema=2.6.0=py36_0
jupyter=1.0.0=py36_3
jupyter_client=5.0.1=py36_0
jupyter_console=5.1.0=py36_0
jupyter_core=4.3.0=py36_0
libpng=1.6.27
markupsafe=0.23=py36_2
matplotlib=2.0.0=np112py36_0
mistune=0.7.4=py36_0
mkl=2017.0.1=0
nbconvert=5.1.1=py36_0
nbformat=4.3.0=py36_0
notebook=5.0.0=py36_0
numpy=1.12.1=py36_0
openssl=1.0.2k
pandas=0.19.2=np112py36_1
pandocfilters=1.4.1=py36_0
path.py=10.3.1=py36_0
pickleshare=0.7.4=py36_0
pip=9.0.1=py36_1
prompt_toolkit=1.0.14=py36_0
pygments=2.2.0=py36_0
pyparsing=2.1.4=py36_0
pyqt=5.6.0=py36_2
python=3.6.1=0
python-dateutil=2.6.0=py36_0
pytz=2017.2=py36_0
pyzmq=16.0.2=py36_0
qt=5.6.2
qtconsole=4.3.0=py36_0
scikit-learn=0.18.1=np112py36_1
scipy=0.19.0=np112py36_0
simplegeneric=0.8.1=py36_1
sip=4.18=py36_0
six=1.10.0=py36_0
sqlite=3.13.0
testpath=0.3=py36_0
tk=8.5.18
tornado=4.5.1=py36_0
traitlets=4.3.2=py36_0
wcwidth=0.1.7=py36_0
wheel=0.29.0=py36_0
widgetsnbextension=2.0.0=py36_0
zlib=1.2.8
```

Comment: You are right, it was not Python 2.7. I found out the first package was a OS package only so that´s why the install doesn't work on a Windows machine. Thanks!